# Accessing filesystem from java within Spring and tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am attempting to do some xml marshalling from with spring/tomcat ... my app is deployed as normal as a war file. The file is indeed copied to the correct location `WEB-INF/classes/myData.xml` but I am unsure how to access this from with Java and specifically my spring service layer. As normally I access files from with the app context itself.

I want to do this :

```
final File xml = new File("WEB-INF/classes/myData.xml");
```

but in my dev build it goes to  *F:\eclipse\WEB-INF\classes\myData.xml* and not the deployment  directory inside tomcat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Spring, a clean way to do this with Java is using `ClasspathResource`:

```
Resource myData = new ClasspathResource("myData.xml"):
```

Alternatively, if this is a Spring bean doing the work, then you can inject it from XML, e.g.

```
<property name="myResource" value="classpath:myData.xml"/>
```

... assuming that `myResource` is a javabean property on your Spring bean of type `Resource`.

The `WEB-INF/classes` directory is automatically on the server's classpath, you don't need to (not should you) specify that in the path explicitly.

The Spring `Resource` interface offers various ways to get hold of the data itself (e.g. `getInputStream()`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are determined to get the path leading to your resource, you can retrieve its URL and then parse it, like this:

```
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    String path = url.toString();
    if (path.startsWith("file:/")) {
        path = path.substring("file:/".length());
        File file = new File(path); 
        ...do something with the file...
    }
```

There is, however, a caveat: your resource may be read directly from the JAR archive, not from a flat file in your filesystem, and thus not really accessible via a File object. The above snipped worked in JBoss (which includes Tomcat), but JBoss explodes a WAR archive before deploying it - not sure if a pure Tomcat will do this as well.

The main question is: why would you really want to get the resource in the form of a File object? Maybe getting its URL is enough for you? Or maybe you just need read access?

If all you need is read access, the simplest way to get any resource on your classpath (like the above web.xml) is by simply calling:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/web.xml")
```

If you want write access to the file, a much better solution would be to pre-configure a directory (for example, via the web.xml), unpack all your needed files there (for example, via the above getResourceAsStream method) and then edit and access them from your predefined directory which is independent from your application server.